# Javascript, Do While Loop multiple options

Tags: javascript

Can you please explain and show the right answer:

```
<p id="show"></p>

<script>

var a = "word1";
var b = "word2";

do {
    color = prompt("Write a word1 or word2 to get out of loop", "");
} while (color != a || color != b);

document.getElementById("show").innerHTML=color;

</script>
```

It works when I delete 'b' option and leave as is only with 'a' option. So how can I use it for multiple options? Also, if you have a solution to keep it simple if I had 15 options for example, it will be great!

Thank you

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

Answer (score 4):

Checking to see if something is not one thing, **or** not another thing, will always be true. I think you want `&&` and not `||`.

More generally, if you've got lots of options, then if the values are strings (or easily-stringified things) then a good pattern is:

```
var badValues = {
  "a": 1, "b": 1, "c": 1, ...
};

do {
  color = prompt("Write a word1 or word2 to get out of loop", "");
} while (!badValues[color]);
```

You could flip the logic around to deal with a "whitelist" instead of a "blacklist".

*edit* — an insightful comment (now removed) pointed out that my statement that the `||` comparison will always be `true` only works when "a" is really different from "b".

Comment: @Asad well yes but that's what I meant by "another thing" :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an array and check whether the string is in the array.

```
var words = ["word1", "word2", "word3"];

do {
    color = prompt("Write a " + words.join(' or ') + " to get out of loop", "");
} while (words.indexOf(color) === -1);

document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = color;
```

Comment: There is also `String.prototype.indexOf`, which works slightly differently but might be preferable, depending on the OPs requirements of course. The good part is that it's supported in ECMAScript ed 3 (so pretty much every browser likely to be in use) and string stuff is very fast. `Array.prototype.indexOf` is ES5 so should be used with a shim and is likely slower (though probably imperceptibly).

Comment: It's supported in IE9+ and all other browsers

Comment: While here I sit in a corporate environment where the SOE is IE 8, and know of places still using IE 6.

Comment: True. Know that I am sorry for that :P